# How to get the size(memory) of a row that gets inserted into netezza

Tags: sql, memory, netezza

I am trying to get the size of a row that gets inserted into Netezza. Are there any in-built views to get the memory of the data which is sitting on NZ tables. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**What I have found?**
_v_sys_object_dslice_info does have the object memory but it doesnt have any details about the memory of each individual record.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the actual size of the data in an individual row, or the size as it sits on disk?  The latter would be a compressed value as Netezza compression is always on.  I'm not aware of any canned view or function that would give this information for a given row, but perhaps if you can describe what you are attempting to accomplish with the info, that might help me think of something.

Comment: I need the size of each record which is being loaded into the NZ table or else the total size of data that is getting loaded per transaction.(As in for each CREATEXID would like to know the no. of records getting loaded into the NZ table.) Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

First create a temp table based on one row of data.

```
create temp  table tmptable as
select *
from Table
limit 1
```

Then check the used bytes of the temp table.  That should be the size per row.

```
select used_bytes
from _v_sys_object_storage_size a inner join
_v_table b
on a.tblid = b.objid
and b.tablename = 'tmptable'
```